# How to Mount local volumes in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mount, osx-yosemite, diskarbitration

I have DADiskRef of drive, i want to mount it programmatically in cocoa.
Here is code i have try to mount drive.

```
 NSString *diskName=[dic valueForKey:@"DAMediaBSDName"]; // i.e. disk1s2
 DASessionRef session = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);

 DADiskRef diskRef= DADiskCreateFromBSDName ( kCFAllocatorDefault, session, [diskName UTF8String]);
 DADiskMountWithArguments( diskRef,NULL,kDADiskMountOptionDefault,OnDiskMount,NULL,NULL);

 // DADiskMount();
```

Here OnDiskMount is implemented below

```
static void OnDiskMount( DADiskRef disk, DADissenterRef dissenter, void * context )
{
    if (dissenter)
    {
      // Error in mounting
    }
    else
    {
      // success
    }
}
```

However this code working perfectly with 10.9 but getting issue while code signing is ON in 10.10.

Comment: Did you overcome your issue on 10.10 while code signing?

Comment: No. still not found solution for this. If you have found any solution then please post your code here.